# Fixing null value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, mysql, django, bash, postgresql

I am building an Electronic Health Record Software. One of my views contains a form that captures the patients basic information.

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from nesting.models import Identity_unique

class Identity_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    NIS = forms.CharField(
                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={

                                'placeholder': 'Enter NIS',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                            }
                )
    )
    First_Name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={

                            'placeholder': 'Enter First Name',
                            'class' : 'form-control'
                        }
            )
    )
    Last_Name = forms.CharField(

       widget=forms.TextInput(
               attrs={

                   'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name',
                   'class' : 'form-control'
               }
        )
    )
    Residence = forms.CharField(

       widget=forms.TextInput(
               attrs={

                   'placeholder': 'Enter Address',
                   'class' : 'form-control'
               }
        )
    )

    DOB = forms.CharField(

           widget=forms.TextInput(
                   attrs={

                       'placeholder': 'Enter Date of Birth',
                       'class' : 'form-control'
                   }
            )
        )
    class Meta:

        model = Identity_unique

        fields = ('NIS', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Residence', 'DOB',)
```

The data schema for the modelForm

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Identity import settings
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Identity_unique(models.Model):

    NIS = models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True,  )
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True, )
    Residence = models.CharField(max_length = 80, blank = True )
    DOB = models.DateField(auto_now = False)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this error each time I attempt to submit saved data to the server:

```
IntegrityError at /nesting/
null value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (Q234934, 2, 2017-10-06 19:17:42.084063+00, Andre, James, nou.self@gmail.com, null, 1991-12-10).
```

I am using postgresql 9.6 for the database. I deleted the migrations folder and migrated the model multiple times but the `null` and `IntegrityError` persists. I also have been looking for the db table Identity_unique in my database but I cannot find it. I was doing that to delete the column with null constraint, because I changed the birthday field from `date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length = 100, default = 0)` to   `DOB = models.DateField(auto_now = False).` As you can see in the error there is a column with a `null` and that is not allowed.

Initially when I used `date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length = 100, null = True)` for the field. I was prompted to add a default value and I added `timezone.now()` in the bash terminal. I am not sure that explains the reason behind the error but I am adding it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

> `null` value in column "date_of_birth" violates not-null constraint

You might not be saving any value to `DOB` column, you need to allow `NULL` value. You should change to

```
DOB = models.DateField(auto_now = False, null = True)
```

You should also make sure `DOB` column in your table allows `null`.